# Angular 15 - Migrating to MDC-based Angular Material Components

Tags: angular, angular15

Updated my Angular app to V15, app is working fine, but some of the component style is breaking because of the style applied on material element tag style name like (`.mat-form-field`, `.mat-raised-button`... etc )

Its working, if I am changing the the tag to `.mat-**mdc**-raised-button` . so my question here
how can I fix this issue at once instead of changing code in each and every file.

Also wanted to know what is best practice for an enterprise application, should we apply the style on tags applied by material or always use CSS class name ?

Comment: can you do search + replace through all files? Maybe with a regex?

Comment: ultimately, even if you run scripts that help with the migration you'll want to only commit component by component because the changes are naturally likely going to be breaking in some fashion

Comment: Hi @Prateek Sharma, is there any official MDC material css classes to refer to, because after upgrading Angular from 14 to 15, I have done MDC migration, which has placed so many TODO(mdc-migration) comments in most of the SCSS files in my application. I am not sure what should be manually updated in these places of TODO comments.

Answer (score 6):

Following the Angular Material Migration Guide [Migrating to MDC-based Angular Material Components :How to Migrate](https://material.angular.io/guide/mdc-migration#how-to-migrate) after you Update to Angular 15 you can run the following command to let it try migrate your Code:

```
ng generate @angular/material:mdc-migration
```

The Migration changed some of the following within my Code:

- CSS add **-mdc-**
  `.mat-header-cell` to
  `.mat-mdc-header-cell`
- Import remove **Legacy**
  `import { MatLegacyTable as MatTable } from '@angular/material/legacy-table';` to
  `import { MatTable } from '@angular/material/table';`
- Add Comments
- ...

You can find these kind of links by following the official [Angular Update Guide](https://update.angular.io/?v=14.0-15.0). Select the correct Versions, check to box `I use Angular Material` and switch Application complexity to `Advanced` to see all information.

Answer (score 5):

After running the `mdc-migration` I still found some places where the old `.mat-...` was used, without an `-mdc` suffix. The easiest to find them was a negative lookahead regex group.

The regex: `\.mat-(?!mdc)`. This matches every `.mat-` string that is not followed by `mdc`.

Using VSCode it is easy to find them, or also replace them.

[image: find and replace example in VSCode]

To run the migration use the following command:

```bash
ng generate @angular/material:mdc-migration
# or
nx generate @angular/material:mdc-migration
```

Answer (score 3):

If you use Nx Workspace, you can use this command below:

`nx g @angular/material:mdc-migration`

Comment: Isn't this the same as `ng generate @angular/material:mdc-migration`  mentioned above

Comment: Yes, It's the same, but it only has an effect when your project is using [Nx Workspace](https://nx.dev/).

Answer (score 1):

I faced the same issue with legacy components, this command seems to do the trick:

```
ng generate @angular/material:mdc-migration
```

Answer (score 1):

For my situation, the answer given by [androbin](https://stackoverflow.com/a/75753940/7230107) was very helpful.

**If in this situation (*please see in the end...*)**

I will simply remember to do the same thing for the use case of classes.

> Search for: "mat-(?!mdc)    Replace with: "mat-mdc-

And after that, I noticed that only the sidenav is not updated they are still using mat-sidenav, mat-sidenav-content, etc.:
[IMG side-nav-after-changed-class-name](https://i.stack.imgur.com/25gkf.png)

> I'm using: "@angular/material": "^16.1.4". Im not sure if this is an isolated case due to my mistakes.

---

I liked the last part of the question. **I see it as a good discussion to be open**.

> Also wanted to know what is best practice for an enterprise application, should we apply the style on tags applied by material or always use CSS class name?

### My answer

I like to use always CSS class names. I use this convention:
same name as the name that is given by Angular Material Team and add a modifier at the end, usually --name-of-project.

### The situation

> The above approach caused the second problem. After replacing only the declaration of CSS classes.

### Reflection

This is not suggested by the Angular Material Team.
[Internal component elements](https://material.angular.io/guide/customizing-component-styles)

> Avoid any custom styles or overrides on internal elements within Angular Material components. The DOM structure and CSS classes applied for each component may change at any time, causing custom styles to break.

This is what I have done. But I'm not afraid, because I know enough CSS to repair custom style breaks after some changes.